# Eliminar elementos de un array con "filter" en javascript

Tags: javascript

He realizado el siguiente ejercicio de freeCodeCamp. Se trata de eliminar elementos de un `array` según unos números recibidos en parámetro.

En la llamada a la función `destroyer` aparece un `array` y, como parámetros segundo y tercero, los números que deben ser eliminados de dicho array.

Este es el código:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  args.splice(0, 1);
  return arr.filter(function(element) {
    return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
  });
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

La primera instrucción está clara: convertir los argumentos de la función en un array real para poder trabajar con él.

La segunda instrucción separa el primer argumento para quedarse con los números a buscar. Pero cuando hago una depuración del proceso, compruebo que arr, el parámetro recibido por la función destroyer, solo contiene `[1,2,3,1,2,3]`

¿Por qué sucede esto? ¿No debería contener el parámetro completo que se envió al invocar a la función? es decir: `([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)`.

Por eso no entiendo la tercera parte, cuando se aplica el filtro sobre el parámetro `arr`. ¿En qué momento han desaparecido del parámetro recibido por `destroyer` los argumentos *2,3* de `arr`?

Y una última pregunta. ¿Por qué hay dos returns? ¿Uno es la respuesta del callback y el otro es la respuesta de destroyer?

Answer (score 3):

Espero esto te sirva como orientación

```js
function destroyer() {
  // Obtengo los Parametros de la funcion, en este caso 3
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  // Dejo en la variable arr el arreglo a intervenir
  var arr = args[0];
  
  // Retorna resultado de la funcion en un arreglo de acuerdo de lo que devuelva el filtro e indexOf
  return arr.filter(function(element) {
    // index of devuelve el indice de la busqueda cuando encuentra un valor, o -1 cuando no encuentra una coincidencia. Osea que el valor 1 al no encontrarlo este retornara -1 
    return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
  });
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que sucede es que la función `filter` regresa un array diferente al original. Por eso cuando haces `arr.filter` literalmente estás filtrando el array y quedándote con el nuevo array ya filtrado dado que eso es lo que estás retornando.

```
return arr.filter
```

Piensa que en lugar de retornar el nuevo array lo pudiste asignar a una variable:

```
var newArray = arr.filter(function(element) {
    return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
});
```

pero en tu caso se lo estás asignando al `return`.

Ahora la cantidad de returns es porque la función [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) necesita un `return` y el otro es de la función `destroyer`.

Answer (score 1):

> "cuando hago una depuración del proceso, compruebo que arr, el parámetro recibido por la función destroyer, solo contiene [1,2,3,1,2,3] ¿Por qué? "

`arr` contiene solo ese array porque la funcion `destoyer` recibe un solo parametro y tu le pasas 3. Asi que `arr` es solo el primero.

> "¿En qué momento han desaparecido del parámetro recibido por destroyer los argumentos 2,3 de arr?"

la variable `args` es la que contiene el 2ndo y 3er parametro (tras hacer `splice` del primer parametro) ya que los obtienes de la llamada, no los que recibe la funcion.

---

Aplicas el filtro sobre `arr` (que contiene el array con los datos) pero le haces un filtro buscando en `args`

la funcion `filter` devuelve del array `arr` todos los valores que no encuentre en el array `args`. Por eso en el log (he editado tu pregunta para que imprima el resultado de `destroyer`) ves que si te deja los valores `1` y `1`.

> "¿Por qué hay dos returns? "

El primer return es el de la funcion `destroyer` y el otro es el de la funcion dentro de `filter`